# Lollipop activity shared element transition with fade

Tags: android, android-transitions

I'm trying to do a simple shared element transition where a row of the clicked list item transitions into the top header view of the resulting activity. I want the top header view to take the position of the list item, fade itself in, then transform to its final position.

This is the simple `sharedElementEnterTransition` that I wrote for the called activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <fade android:fadingMode="fade_out" />
    <changeBounds />
    <changeTransform />
    <changeImageTransform />
</transitionSet>
```

However, the `fade` transition isn't doing anything. I see the resulting view suddenly pop up on the spot then transforms to the final position.

Here's where I start the activity

```
view.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(...);
    view.setTransitionName("test");
    final ActivityOptions options = 
        ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, view, "test");
    startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
});
```

Can't quite figure out what's happening. Anyone has any ideas? The layout codes are exactly what you would expect with with `android:transitionName="test"`.

Comment: Just a wild guess, I don't think <fade android:fadingMode="fade_out" />
works alone without the backend coding support. Perhaps do something with the header code?

Comment: That's my guess too, but I have tried setting the default `visibility` and `alpha` on the target view with no success. I'm not sure how to tell the transition framework to set the starting state of the target views.

Comment: Can you trying setting those variables in coding instead of the xml file?

Comment: have a look at (Activity Transitions With Shared Elements) in this tutorial to get an idea on how it works -- http://www.raywenderlich.com/103367/material-design

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile debugging Visibility class, I figured out that target view was not the expected one, therefore I forced it to test it, and it seems working. However, I don't know if this is the perfect solution, because I also agreed that it should work as other transitions (automatically)

```
sharedElementEnterTransition = Fade(Visibility.MODE_IN).addTarget(your_view)
```

If you want a sequential transitions, you might need to create a TransitionSet and add it

```
val fadeIn = Fade(Visibility.MODE_IN).addTarget(your_view)
val move =  TransitionInflater.from(context) 
                    .inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move)

val transitionSet = TransitionSet().apply {
           ordering = ORDERING_TOGETHER
           addTransition(move)
           addTransition(fadeIn)
        }

sharedElementEnterTransition = transitionSet
```